# The state in reactjs doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The state in reactjs Class doesn't change, although i used setState, returned an Object, and bind the function in the constructor, here's my code

```
export default class Vacations extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sat: false,
            sun: true,
            mon: false,
            tue: false,
            wed: false,
            thu: false,
            fri: false
        }
        this.handleEnabledChange = this.handleEnabledChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleEnabledChange(e){
        const targetName = e.target.name;
        const checkState = e.target.checked;
        console.log(targetName, checkState);
        this.setState((preState)=>{
            return Object.assign({},{
                ...preState,
                name: !checkState
            })
        }) 
    }

    render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <Checkbox name="sat" checked={this.state.sat} label="Saturday" onChange={this.handleEnabledChange} disabled/>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: Maybe you can share the Checkbox component as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simple

```
handleEnabledChange(e){
    const targetName = e.target.name;
    const currentState = this.state[targetName]

    this.setState({
      [targetName]: !currentState
    })
}
```

Also I notice you have `disabled` props on checkbox. Checkbox event will not fire for disabled control.

Answer (score 0):

The state gets changed, but you are adding a new property `name` to the state:

```
return Object.assign({},{
    ...preState,
    name: !checkState
})
```

You are not changing the value of `sat`, which is why your component doesn't show any visible updates. Note how you never use `targetName`.

You should be doing:

```
this.setState({[targetName]: !checkState});
```

There is no need to use a callback since you are not reading from the previous state and you don't have to merge the previous state manually, React does that for you.